# Why does an LED reduce the amount of current flowing in a circuit

Tags: electricity, electronics

Am new to electronics and am trying to make sense of something am not able to understand.
I have the following setup

[image]

When i measure the current between the LED and the 220 ohms resistor am getting 1.42mA

By removing the LED and measuring the current between the resistor and negative terminal am getting 13.82mA

I have measured the voltage drop across the LED as 2.90V and voltage drop across the resistor as 0.33v

why is the current flow different when there is an led and when an led is removed since from the ohm law i expected

situation 1: When there is no LED

$$I=\frac{V}{R}$$
$$I = \frac{3.25}{220} = 14.78mA\ .$$

And when there is an LED to get

$$I=\frac{3.25-0.33}{220} = 13.27mA\ .$$

That is by removing the voltage drop across the resistor youll get the voltage across the LED

But when the LED is present am getting a current of 1.42mA instead of 13.27mA

Where am i going wrong. Is it my wrong multimeter or are my calculations wrong?

Comment: The LED isn't there to draw current anymore.

Comment: Dont you think that LED also has a barrier potential just like all PN juction

Comment: Your second current calculation is incorrect.

Comment: It might be interesting to a look at [LED's voltage drop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76367/accounting-for-led-resistance).

Answer (score 3):

You said the voltage drop on the LED is 2.90 V.
Why then take it as 0.33V?
In the case with the LED you should calculate the current as 
$$ I= \frac{(3.25-2.90)V}{220 \Omega} \simeq 1.5 mA  $$

The fact that you neglect the internal resistance of the source may explain the small difference between the measured and the calculated results. The ammeter and voltmeter have internal resistances too.